# google maps V2 available on google TV android 3.2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-tv, google-play-services

I'm developing an android app which runs on devices 2.X up.
 It uses Google maps V2 API.

I just installed the app in logitech revue Google TV with android 3.2 and maps do not work. I looked up and Google play services does not seem to be installed.

I looked it up on the play store and it does not show up, neither google maps official app.

So i guess google maps native api is not available on any google tv?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that ARM-based Google TV devices should get updated to 4.2 later this year; perhaps Maps V2 will work on them then.

Comment: Unfortunately the Revue is the 1st-gen Intel model, so it will always be stuck on 3.2.

Comment: what about google maps v1?

Answer (score 1):

Even when Google Play Services hits your TV, I don't think Google Maps Android API v2 was optimized for devices without touch screen. Some more work has to be done there in the implementation before it is sensible to use API V2 on TVs.

Comment: Is it possible to use Google Maps Geolocation API on Android TV?